# Functions, structures, compound literals, incorrect output

Tags: c, function, structure

Please, take a look at a program that is supposed to deliver tomorrow's date. The program is from a textbook, and uses three functions. 
Unfortunately, it delivers a wrong output:

```
Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy):  09 25 1977
Tomorrow's date is 00/10/25.
```

But sometimes it does deliver a correct output:

```
Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy):  10 07 2015
Tomorrow's date is 10/08/15.
```

I don't see why this happens.
Here is the program:

```
// Program to determine tomorrow's date

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct date today1, tomorrow;
    struct date tomorrow_date (struct date today);

    printf("Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy):  ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &today1.month, &today1.day, &today1.year);

    tomorrow = tomorrow_date (today1);

    printf ("Tomorrow's date is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i.\n", tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, tomorrow.year % 100);

    return 0;
}
// Function to find the number of days in a month
int number_of_days (struct date d)
{
    int days;
    bool is_leap (struct date d);

    const int days_per_month[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if (is_leap (d) == true && d.month == 2)
        days = 29;
    else
        days = days_per_month[d.month - 1];

    return days;
}

// Function to determine if it's a leap year

bool is_leap (struct date d)
{
    bool leap_year;

    if ( (d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % 100 != 0) || (d.year % 400 == 0))
        leap_year = true;
    else
        leap_year = false;

    return leap_year;
}

// Function to determine tomorrow's date using compound literals

struct date tomorrow_date (struct date today)
{
    struct date tomorrow;
    int number_of_days(struct date d);

    if (today.day != number_of_days(today))
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today.month, today.day + 1, today.year};

    else if (today.month == 12) // end of year
        tomorrow = (struct date) {1, 1, today.year + 1};

    else // end of month
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today.month + 1, 1, today.year};  

    return tomorrow;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you put function prototype inside other functions ?

Comment: @ameyCU: I don't like this type of prototype usage, but this is the way they use it in the book, saying that it is just for safety

Answer (score 2):

You use the format specifier `%i` when you scan the date. This specifier reads decimal integers, but accepts the forms that C code also accepts, namely hex ( `0xff`) and octal (`0377`).

The inputs `08` and `09` are treated as octal, but they are not legal octal numbers, because octal has no digit 8 or 9. Scanning stops at the first non-octal digit. (By the way, you don't check that `sscanf` returns 3.)

The remedy is to replace the `%i` format with `%d`, which scans `08` as human readers would expect.

Answer (score 0):

By presenting input as 09 you are trigering input in octal base. Remove the leading 0 in month input. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Solve this by using `%d` and not `%i`.